# Best way to implement a pictures table in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website with a lot of pictures in it.  Currently I just have the pictures all on the server and I use php to get the files in the directory and display them all one my one in a table.  However, when I do this the pictures are displayed alphabetically which I don't want.  I want them to be displayed my insertion time.  Which I was thinking I could create a table with a number field set to auto increment and then the file name of the inserted picture.  and just leave the pictures on the server.  So everytime I insert a picture it will insert a row with a number and file name.  So when I display I just display by that number Desc, which should give me the pictures by newest inserted.  Is this the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good to me. If you really wanted to get technical, you could use a timestamp field and order them by that. However, it sounds like your idea would work fine as long as you auto increment as you insert your images.

Comment: The timestamp data type can also default to current_timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. I'd use a timestamp (of type `DATETIME`) to determine exactly when the picture was uploaded, and sort by that. An incrementing ID doesn't always correspond with the time of insertion.

Comment: I don't see the need for this. Sorting by the actual create date on the file on the file system should be enough. No need for another table at all.

Comment: Having a table of information about the files you enter into the filesystem is always a good idea. What you do with that information is another thing. Yes, you could sort by timestamp, but having a table is a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by an auto_incremented id field, or you could store the timestamps and order them that way. Either one is an okay option, just make sure that you're avoiding potential primary key violations.

Answer (score 0):

With `filemtime()` you get the timestamp of a file. So it is possible to define an ordering with `uasort()` - or one of the other php sorting functions - after you get the files with (for example) `readdir()`. No database is necessary for that.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a pointer to the file in your database would be the best way to go about it and have the images in a file system. As for the date created, you could use  `DATETIME` to keep track of the time it was created and then query for them in the order you wanted them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for this. There must be a way in PHP to get all the list of files and sort by date created. Since this files will be uploaded to your server, the date_created time will be the date created on your server; hence, no need for a new table and database call, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planing on having thousands (or more) of photos on in your system you need to use a database table for meta-data while storing the actual image files on the hard drive.

Doing 10,000 I/O hits to sort the files by date is nuts. Doing one SQL query to return a list of all file names ordered by date is much better since MySQL will probably be able to fit the entire table into memory.

```
table image
{
    id
    user_id (if images belong to certain users)
    path (the file system path and/or filename)
    created (timestamp)
}
```